# Source for finishing the entire Mishnayos for Shloshim

Tags: minhag, mishna, mourning-aveilus

Lo aleinu someone has passed away in my life, and I am wondering about the customs that relate to aveilus. I have noticed that people have the [custom](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/371240/jewish/The-Shloshim.htm) of splitting the entire Mishnayos to be learned for the merit of a deceased in time to finish the entire Shas before the shloshim. Although I have found [sources](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.376.13?vhe=Arukh_HaShulchan,_Yoreh_De%27ah_--_Wikisource&lang=bi) that mention learning Mishnayos for the deceased, I could not find a source for this specific custom. Where does it come from?

Comment: I'm not sure that it needs a specific source. If you accept learning mishnayos for the deceased, it's not hard to imagine that if the deceased is VERY IMPORTANT you'd want to arrange to learn THE MOST mishnayos. The most is all and usually everyone thinks their relative is very important.

Comment: @DoubleAA You could assign the same masechta to anyone willing to participate, but there seems to something about covering the whole mishnayos.