# Splitting learning for a siyum

Tags: minhag, torah-study, siyum

For various purposes such as the one discussed in [Source for finishing the entire Mishnayos for Shloshim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139487/source-for-finishing-the-entire-mishnayos-for-shloshim), people organize projects to complete some section of Torah (e.g. an order of Mishna) collectively, with each participant taking a different part, and then for the collective to make a *siyum* on the whole section. **Are there sources discussing whether this is a legitimate practice?** One might expect that a *siyum* would be an appropriate celebration of one large achievement in learning as opposed to a bunch of parallel small ones.

Comment: Quite related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9409/group-coordination-for-a-siyum

Comment: Usually the hallmark of a "real" bona-fide siyum is firstborns breaking their fast on 14 nissan. I don't know that I've ever seen a group-siyum used in that fashion.

Comment: @DoubleAA It seems to me that saying the special Kaddish would depend on it being "real."

Comment: Sdei Chemed.....

Comment: @DoubleAA how about Abaye's feast for the Sages in Shabbat 118b, and Rama on YD 246:26? Not in terms of a group-siyum, but as a "bona fide" siyum

Comment: @IsaacMoses why?

Comment: @RabbiKaii What about it

Answer (score 5):

Rabbi Lauffer at Ohr Somayach [writes](https://ohr.edu/explore/daf_yomi/8107):

> Is It Permissible for a Few People to Learn Different Parts of the
> Tractate and Make a Siyum Together?
>
> Yes, it is (see Chavot Yair 70 and Maharshal). If possible, all
> those who learned the tractate should endeavor to gather together and
> to celebrate collectively.

On the other hand, in his chapter on the Nine Days (p. 59:n.48), Rav Simcha Bunim Cohen brings a machlokes between the [Kinyan Hatorah B'halacha (5:52)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22066&st=&pgnum=80&hilite=):

[image]

and the [Vayivarech Dovid (1:24)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9755&st=&pgnum=122):

[image]

Rabbi Cohen (5:c:i) follows Rav Dovid Harfenes and paskens in the English section of the sefer: "Meat and wine may not be served at a collective siyum; i.e., a siyum celebrated after each person of a group studied a different section of hte same sefer. Even though every word of the sefer was studied, no one individual studied the entire volume."